# SQL Update statement for a particular person

Tags: sql, oracle

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this update statement i want it to update the title of Dr Edders and then display Dr Edders after the statement has been run.

```
UPDATE Staff SET Title = 'Dr' WHERE StaffLName = 'Edders';
SELECT Title, StaffLName FROM Staff WHERE StaffLName = 'Edders';
```

Comment: What RDBMS? And what's wrong with this query?

Comment: i am using sql plus the query it says missing expression

Comment: Oh wait, you need to add the table name in your select query.

Comment: You're missing the `FROM` clause from the second statement.

Comment: SQL> UPDATE Staff SET Title = 'Miss' WHERE StaffLName = 'Edders' AND SELECT Titl
e, StaffLName FROM Staff WHERE StaffLName = 'Edders'; still missing expression can you have a select statement after an update?

Comment: Your second query is using fancy quotes.  Replace them with simple single quotes.

Comment: Your comment above makes it look like you aren't doing two queries (as in your question) but have mangled them into one (with an 'AND" in between). Is this the case? If so - do they work when you actually do them as two separate queries like in your question above?

Comment: In which case - remove the "AND" and replace it with a ";" (which ends the query and starts a new one) otherwise SQL thinks you're trying to do just one query

Answer (score 0):

For oracle you can use `RETURNING INTO` clause to return what you are updating, deleting or even inserting

You can find more information here [DML RETURNING INTO Clause](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/dml-returning-into-clause.php)

---

For SQL Server you can use `OUTPUT` clause

Find the MSDN page here [OUTPUT Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms177564.aspx)

---

Apart from which database you are using, you can also put your `UPDATE` and `SELECT` statement into a procedure and execurte the stored procedure.